# Как покрасить строки и столбцы по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, визуализация

Нужно покрасить те значения `col4` и `col5`, которые не совпадают с `col2` и `col3` соответственно в желтый цвет, удаленную строку в зеленый и добавленную в синий. Я это сделала, но у меня красятся индексы тоже, а нужно, чтобы они оставались не покрашенными.

[Пример данных](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HtE86gHAgqqI0LyAKt8RjT2UlW4-hl6Zc85Uqo6XtHg/edit#gid=0).

````
i = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
changed_mask = ~(df1.loc[i] == df2.loc[i]) #this df will have True values where df2 is not the same as df1
shared = df2.loc[i] #color this using changed_mask
removed = df1.loc[df1.index.difference(df2.index)] #add this dataframe in any way you want
added = df2.loc[df2.index.difference(df1.index)] 

def highlight_diff(data,removed=removed, added=added, color='#FFFF00'):
    a = data.index.intersection(removed.index)
    b = data.index.intersection(added.index)
    

    
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    
    other = data.xs('Первоначальный файл', axis='columns', level=-1)
    finish = pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, 'color:black'),index=data.index,
                         columns=data.columns)
    
    finish.loc[a, :] = 'background-color: #D8E4BC'
    finish.loc[b, :] = 'background-color: #B8CCE4'
    

#     finish.index = 'background-color: white'
#     finish.loc[:,('1', '')] = 'background-color: white'
    

    return finish  
        ```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
finish.loc[a, :] = 'background-color: #D8E4BC'
```

В этой строке кода вы присваиваете строку с цветом выбранным по `a` строкам, но **всем столбцам** фрейма `finish`. То есть, идет выделение всех столбцов строки.

Укажите явно, какие столбцы нужно подкрасить:

```
finish.loc[a, ['col4', 'col5']] = 'background-color: #D8E4BC'
```

Comment: finish = pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, 'color:black'),index=data.index,
                         columns=data.columns) я крашу в желтый здесь и индексы красяться в желтый.

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, можете привести примеры данных для `removed` и `added` ?

Comment: привела в вопросе

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, а что есть `df1` и `df2`? ;)

Comment: на примере из файла  - col1 - col3(df1), col4-col6(df2). По три столбца на каждый дата фрейм

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, `changed_mask = ~(df1.loc[i] == df2.loc[i])` - генерирует исключительную ситуацию: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1w7y3ts0ohvB2F-5CQQv8XfcFoapbelYa

Comment: в папке полный код программы и два файла

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, это конечно замечательно, но хотелось бы увидеть в вопросе [mcve] ;)

Comment: я уже решила задачу, спасибо. Ваш ответ я приму.

Comment: хотите поучаствовать в проекте по прогнозированию популярности постов в социальных сетях( part time, remote)? За подробностями в личку  (login - aljona_Barbanova telegram)